# Returning cross join instead of inner join

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two result sets from database into object and when I inner join them, it returns cross join. Following is my code:

```
var nw = new NorthwindEntities();
var employee1 = (from emp in nw.Employees
                 join ord in nw.Orders on emp.EmployeeID equals ord.EmployeeID
                 where emp.EmployeeID == 5
                 select new
                 {
                     empID = emp.EmployeeID,
                     empName = emp.FirstName,
                     ordDate = ord.OrderDate
                 }).ToList();

var employee2 = (from emp in nw.Employees
                 join ord in nw.Orders on emp.EmployeeID equals ord.EmployeeID
                 where emp.EmployeeID == 5
                 select new
                 {
                     empID = emp.EmployeeID,
                     empName = emp.FirstName,
                     shpAddress = ord.ShipAddress
                 }).ToList();

var employee = from e1 in employee1
               join e2 in employee2 on new { e1.empID } equals new { e2.empID }
               select new
               {
                   empID = e1.empID,
                   empName = e1.empName,
                   ordDate = e1.ordDate,
                   orAdd = e2.shpAddress
               };

gvAll.DataSource = employee.ToList();
```

Now when I join employee1 and employee2 into employee, I get a cross join of those data set. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My main target behind this is to have data returned from database stored in some place temporarily so I can work it with later with other data retrieved from database.

employee1 and employee2 uses same query for employee id (5) except employee1 has empID, empName and OrderDate where as employee2 has empID, empName and shipAddress. Now I want empID, empName, OrderDate and ShipAddress out of employee1 and employee2 in employee. empID is common in both but I am getting a cross join. Thank you.

Comment: It obviously will give the cross join, because empId is same on all the records of employee1 and employee2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `employee1` and `employee2` you will aslo need the `OrderId` column to and then join them by both cos you need to get an equal unique key on both tables.

and from what you wrote I think that `empID` is not unique in either tables cos you can have more orders for same `empID`

So first you need a unique key on both `employee1` and `employee2` then you can join on that.

Comment: `employee1` and `employee2` uses same query for employee id (5) except `employee1` has `empID, empName and OrderDate` where as `employee2 has empID, empName and shipAddress`. Now I want `empID, empName, OrderDate and ShipAddress` out of `employee1` and `employee2` in `employee`. empID is common in both but I am getting a cross join. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The result returned from function  is logically correct, it is not a cross join. `empID` has some duplicate row in some table so, data is looking like a cross join.
Use `distinct` then it will return your desired output.